# Sentinel value at the end of a file?

Tags: java, file, while-loop, eof, sentinel

I read in the contents of my `File` likewise:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
while( scanner.hasNextLine())
{
  list.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

At the `EOF` I want to send the `String "@@@"` to act as a Sentinel Value to know that its the end. However, I do not have `"@@@"` in the `File` that is being read into. Any suggestions on how I might approach this?

Comment: If your storing the lines in a List, why do want the sentinel value?  The last element of the List is the EOF.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
while( scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    list.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
list.add("@@@");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line `list.add("@@@");` after your while loop.

You'll know you've read the entire file in by then, so just add the constant string. You may want to consider separating out the string for readability with something like:

```
public static final String SENTINEL = "@@@";
```